# Image::Magick::constant not defined

Tags: perl, imagemagick, perl-module

Does anyone know the cause of the following error:

> Image::Magick::constant not defined.
> The required ImageMagick libraries are 
>   not installed or not installed properly.

I've seen a number of posts related to this on the web, but no real resolution.
I'm using ActivePerl 5.16.3 (MSWin32-x86-multi-thread) on a windows 7 desktop with ImageMagick-6.8.4-Q16 installed.
 The library appears to install correctly from the included "Image-Magick.ppd" file, with the DLL and supporting files installed in the expected Perl module locations.
Is it possible that the compiled Image::Magick DLL is not compatible with a multi-thread version of Perl?

Comment: Is it possible you have 64-bit Image Magick and 32-bit Perl? I *did* have ActivePerl 5.16 and Image Magick working on a Windows 7 machine, both 64-bit versions. Unfortunately not got that machine any more to reference versions etc for you. Was also a real pain to set up MinGW 64-bit to enable stuff to get compiled.

Comment: The Image Magick install was the 32-bit version ("ImageMagick-6.8.4-5-Q16-x86-dll.exe"). The desktop is a 32-bit system so if I had a 64-bit version then the included "imdisplay.exe" wouldn't be able to run, and it does without errors. Still, packaging errors do sometimes happen, and just on the off chance the wrong version of the "Magick.dll" was included in the PPD distribution, I verified that the DLL located at "C:\Perl\site\lib\auto\Image\Magick\Magick.dll" does have an "i386" header ("01 4C" starting at offset 4A).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really know why this resolves the issue, but I did a rollback to ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16, changed the path statement to reference the older version of "ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16" and reinstalled the Image-Magick PPD in the 6.8.3 directory using PPM, then rebooted the system again.

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\PerlMagick>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Binary build 1603 [296746] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Mar 13 2013 11:29:21

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.


C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\PerlMagick>ppm install Image-Magick.ppd
Unpacking Image-Magick-6.82...done
Generating HTML for Image-Magick-6.82...done
Updating files in site area...done
   2 files unchanged
   6 files updated

C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.3-Q16\PerlMagick>
```

My code now runs without the "Image::Magick::constant not defined" error. I'm not sure if this indicates a problem with my desktop config or a conflict with ActivePerl 5.16.3 and ImageMagick-6.8.4-Q16 but it resolved my issue.